# IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState when I send to save a form and minimize application

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

I have a form that when filled out and I click the save button it triggers a request to save the data on the server. When the response arrives, I call `removeFragment` to remove the form screen and go back to the previous screen and call `reloadActivity` to load the list of updated items. So I found that when I click save and minimize the app, it crashes giving me the error “IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState”. How can I do the entire process of submitting the form, removing the fragment from the stack and updating the list even when the app is not running in the foreground?

In my fragment:

```
User user = new User(123, "John Doe");
Call<User> call = apiService.createuser(user);
call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
   if(response != null && response.issuccessful()){
       removeFragment();
       reloadActivity();
   }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
   listener.onError(t.getMessage());
}
```

In MyActivity:

```
public void removeFragment() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() == 1) {
        finish();
    } else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

the way it works normal, only crash when the application is minimized. Can someone help me?

Comment: I guess use the `update` Fragment method instead of `remove`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand

Answer (score 0):

It crashes because you are trying to remove a fragment from a Lifecycle that is paused or stopped. Mainly caused by having async code that has access to stuff that don't "exist" at the time of response.
The quickest option is to have the Fragment manage the User creation and then you send the User back to the Activity, and close the fragment immediately. The Activity handles the api request, response, and updates its own view.

This shouldn't crash your app if its sent to the background, and you should be pulling fresh data at onResume/onStart anyways so it will be up to date.

Comment: avalerio could you give me a code as an example of this theory?